# Installation of OpenBUGS in UBUNTU is not working

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install OpenBUGS-3.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04. I used the following command in terminal (after downloading and extracting OpenBUGS-3.2.3.tar.gz) :

```
cd OpenBUGS-3.2.3/

sudo ./configure

sudo make

sudo make install
```

No error came while installing. But when I typed "OpenBUGS" in terminal to open the software, the following error occurs:

```
OpenBUGS

/usr/local/bin/OpenBUGSCli: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenBUGS.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems that the installation was not proper.

Please help me out to get a proper installation of OpenBUGS in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when trying to install openBUGS (already during the installation, directly after the "make" command) - This link has worked for me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/470796/fatal-error-sys-cdefs-h-no-such-file-or-directory

It seems that there were some files we were missing to properly use the c library. libc6-dev-i386 contains these files.

Good luck!